# Delete external task topics in Camunda

Tags: camunda

Do the external task topics get deleted after their usage or they remain indefinitely? We have dynamic topics (with a UUID in it’s name) which has only one time usage. So, over a period of time, there would be a lot of topics created. Can we delete the topics if they are no more needed?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Also answered here: https://forum.camunda.io/t/what-is-the-life-cycle-of-an-external-task-topic/50957.

But for reference here, there is no direct storage of the topic in any camunda tables. Actually the topic name is saved in the table ACT_RU_EXT_TASK as part of the external task. Once all external tasks associated with a topic are completed, those entries will be gone from the database.